# Can anybody state the origin of this verse?

Tags: scripture, shiva, mantras, identification-request, shloka

While searching for a particular topic, I came across this verse.

> शूद्रो वा यदि वाऽन्योऽपि चण्डालोऽपि जटाधरः । दीक्षितः शिवमन्त्रेण सभस्माङ्गः शिवो भवेत् ।।
>
> Translation: *Śūdra*s or any other person, even if he happens to be a *caṇḍāla*; become verily *Śiva* Himself on bearing matted locks & holy ash after being duly initiated into *Śiva*'s mantra.

Currently, this verse appears in the *Pañcatantra*. However the text being secular in nature, can't be quoted for religious matters as a matter of principle. So can anybody tell in which *Purāṇa* or *Āgama* this verse occurs ?